# URL hacking with record type selection and prepopulating values for Grand Parent

Tags: visualforce, community, custom-button, urlhacking

Object : Account
Field: X Picklist

Object : Contact
Field : Account__c Lookup

Object: Extension
Field: Contact__c
      RecordType - 3 recordTypes available
      X Picklist

suppose account A1 has X= 'test' and a related contact C1. when i click on the new Extension button on contact related List i want system to navigate to Record type selection page. After selecting a Record Type system should Redirect me to another page where X field is prepopulated with 'test' value for x field and the selected record Type. Can anyone propose any alternative solution to this type of URL hacking.

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: It seems you are assuming that the reader would know common SFDC URL hacks and thus be able to comment. Perhaps if you provided examples of these URL hacks you might get more interest.

Comment: How about using a Visualforce page instead of a URL hack? This option would be more supportable, and it would work better in Salesforce1 as well.